# Notification with Service Android

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that's started with a broadcastreceiver.

In this service, I want to send notification every minute. 
The problem is: I'm receiving the message only one time.

Question: What do I need to do, to receive the message each minute?

This is my code.

**MANIFEST.XML**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />      
<application>
    <receiver android:name="com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions.MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions.NotificationService"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </service>
</application>
```

**SERVICE**

```
package com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions;

import com.polifrete.polifreteandroid.MainActivity;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationService extends Service {

public static final int time = 60 * 1000;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE CREATE");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE START");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE COMMAND");
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
                showNotification();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public void showNotification() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Test Notification")
            .setContentText("Test Notification.")
            .setSmallIcon(
                    com.polifrete.polifreteandroid.R.drawable.ic_actionbar)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, n.build());

}
```

}

**BROADCAST**

```
package com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Script", "Passou RECEIVER");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    context.startService(i);
}
```

}

Comment: I dont know why, but sometimes its passing on receiver and sometime not... can someone help me plz?

Answer (score 0):

you are setting still same notification id=0 in line `notificationManager.notify(0, n.build());`. Set any Random value (`(int)(Math.random()*10000);`). Same id causes overwritting existing notification with same id.
Also you should set below line for differ `PendingIntent`s

```
intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
...
notificationManager.notify((int)(Math.random()*10000), n.build());
```

also you should use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) instead of sleeping `Thread`

Answer (score 0):

you should change to this one

```
  while(true){

        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
            showNotification();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

if you use same notification id then next notifications will just replace previous one, if you want them to be separate just use other id for next notification.

Comment: Ive changed the block, and put a diferent ID for my notifications, but still appearing just one notification...

Comment: @Felipe A.
you use random generator for notification ids?

Comment: try to show different data inside notif, as I see now you show same hardcoded string.  Try to use random generator to show it as text of notification. Then you will know is it really same notif or just updates of previous one

Comment: This notification using broadcast receiver, when i try to use on ADV it work, when i use it on device, not working, do u have any ideia?